# A polynomial is called a Fermat's polynomial...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, polynomials, proof-writing

A polynomial is called a Fermat polynomial if it can be written as the sum of the squares
of two polynomials with integer coefficients. Suppose that $f(x)$ is a Fermat polynomial such
that $f(0) = 1000$. Prove that $f(x) + 2x$ is not a Fermat polynomial.

What I have done:

Let $p(x)$ be a Fermat polynomial such that $p(0)$ is divisible by $4$. Suppose that
$p(x) = g(x)^2+h(x)^2$ where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients. Therefore
$g(0)^2 + h(0)^2$ is divisible by $4$. Since $g(0)$ and $h(0)$ are integers, their squares are either $1 (mod 4)$ or $0 (mod 4)$. It therefore follows that $g(0)$ and $h(0)$ are even.
From here, I can not proceed any further. Please help

Comment: Is it from RMO 2013 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $2 \mid g(0)$, lets look at the coefficient of $X$ in $g(X)^2$, we have, say
$$ g(X) = a_nX^n + \ldots + a_1X + 2b_0 $$
hence
$$ g(X)^2 = a_n^2X^{2n} + \ldots + 4a_1b_0X + 4b_0^2 $$
so the coefficient of $X$ in $g(X)^2$ is a multiple of $4$, the same for $h(X)^2$. So the $X$-coefficient of any Fermat polynomial $p$ with $4\mid p(0)$ is a multiple of $4$.

Now $f(0) + 2\cdot 0 = f(0) = 1000$, hence if both $f$ and $f + 2X$ were Fermat polynomials their $X$-coefficients were both multiples of $4$. But their difference is 2.

Comment: @martini.Thanks, I get it now!! That was great help!